# py2app error: in find_needed_modules TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, macos, macports, py2app

I have some troubles with py2app; for some reason I have always the same error for all scripts that I developed. At the moment I am using last MacPorts version and after two days of testing I cannot figure out what is wrong.

One of the setup.py file for py2app is:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes': ['sip', 'PyQt4._qt', 'PyQt4.QtCore', 'PyQt4.QtGui'],
    'excludes': ['PyQt4.QtDesigner', 'PyQt4.QtNetwork', 'PyQt4.QtOpenGL', 'PyQt4.QtScript', 'PyQt4.QtSql', 'PyQt4.QtTest', 'PyQt4.QtWebKit', 'PyQt4.QtXml', 'PyQt4.phonon']}

setup(
      app=APP,
      options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
      setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

And this is the log:

```
python setup.py py2app
running py2app
creating /Users/opensw/SkyDrive/SISSA/Kymograph/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/python2.7-standalone/app
creating /Users/opensw/SkyDrive/SISSA/Kymograph/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/python2.7-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/opensw/SkyDrive/SISSA/Kymograph/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/python2.7-standalone/app/temp
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/python2.7-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/python2.7-standalone/app/Frameworks
*** using recipe: virtualenv ***
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named matplotlib-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named scipy-0
*** using recipe: sip ***
*** using recipe: matplotlib ***
*** using recipe: scipy ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/opensw/SkyDrive/SISSA/Kymograph/py2app-0.7.3-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 553, in run
    self._run()
  File "/Users/opensw/SkyDrive/SISSA/Kymograph/py2app-0.7.3-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 741, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/Users/opensw/SkyDrive/SISSA/Kymograph/py2app-0.7.3-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 816, in run_normal
    self.process_recipes(mf, filters, flatpackages, loader_files)
  File "/Users/opensw/SkyDrive/SISSA/Kymograph/py2app-0.7.3-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 710, in process_recipes
    find_needed_modules(mf, packages=rval['packages'])
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/modulegraph/find_modules.py", line 199, in find_needed_modules
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that some bad input has been passed to the algorithm which attempts to detect dependancies in order to package them into your app - one of the places where I have had trouble with this has been in use of github flavoured markdown in package README.md files.

This is a general guide to debugging setup.py issues, or actually python issues in general.

1. Run it again in interactive mode, i.e. `python -i setup.py py2app`. Once `setup.py` exits you will find yourself in a python prompt.
2. Run `from pdb import pm; pm()`. You should now find yourself at a debug prompt.
3. Type `up` and hit enter - you are now a frame higher in the stack - you can type `list` to see where in the source code the current frame is positioned, and `args` to see the arguments passed to the current frame (usually a function or method). You can also run python commands to inspect the current state, and run `pp var` to pretty-print that variable.
4. Once you have repeated the above step a few times you will find where the error is encountered - in the case I encountered where it was a README file I found a variable called `lineno` which gave the line of my README file which caused the error. If your problem is a module import, it'll probably be something different, but my instinct is that you'll find yourself looping over the `packages` argument seen in your stack trace, and the current list item will be the key to your problem.

Comment: @user2105584 did you manage to use it to resolve your issue? If not I'm happy to add more info to improve my answer

Comment: Thanks for this - really useful tips, not just for setup debugging.

Comment: @theheadofabroom would you mind helping me with this issue? I am having a similar problem in which I can only create Alias mode apps- not Normal mode distribution apps. I keep getting import errors for the sip recipe and an insane amount of traceback errors. I am definitely not experienced enough to debug all of this and I am sure the fix is a simple one. I just do not know where to start. Here is my original run in normal mode: https://pastebin.com/dd7DUQcB and here is the beginning of the traceback error lines https://pastebin.com/LUi2wRWT. I do not understand why this is happening. Thanks!

Comment: @gmonz Could you open a new question for this and put a link in here?

Comment: @theheadofabroom I really wish I could and I would but for some reason I have unfairly been banned from asking questions. Perhaps you could open a question with the contents of my comment and post an answer to your own question, which I will mark as an answer and upvote? Sorry for the confusion- I am quite annoyed with the mods for banning me rather than suspending me for something I did not even do.Now I am just trying to contribute to the community in the hopes of an unban. I could not find an answer that worked for me anywhere.Sorry for the hassle and I understand if you don't want to help.

Comment: same problem as @gmonz. Any solution?